# Maximum likelihood of logistic PDF?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, maximum-likelihood

Starting from the "usual" case where we use the Bernoulli combined with logistic distribution for binary dependent variables:

$$ \prod_{i=1}^{n} \left(\pi\right)^{y_i} \left(1-\pi\right)^{1-y_i}$$

with $\pi = F(\eta) = \frac{1}{1+\exp(-\eta)}$ being the logistic distribution function.

If we instead define $f(\eta)$ as:
$$
f(\eta) = \frac{\partial F(\eta)}{\partial \eta} = \frac{\exp(-\eta)}{(1+\exp(-\eta))^2}
$$
and thus derive the probability density function (pdf), we have the starting point from what is usually done in the maximum likelihood machinery, namely assume iid and then denote the joint density as a product of marginal densities:

$$\prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\exp(-\eta_i)}{(1+\exp(-\eta_i))^2}$$

But since I never came across this kind of maximum likelihood I am asking myself whether this would even make any sense? I guess with this likelihood we are not in the (0,1)-case anymore, since the Bernoulli distribution no longer involved.

Would be interested how that is called, if it is used (or why that is not useful). Thanks!

Comment: This makes no sense. The "logistic distribution function" is not employed in any sense as a probability distribution here: it is the *link* function.

Comment: This [previous question & answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/304988) might clarify.